# DXL : Comparing attributes of objects across modules

Tags: attributes, ibm-doors

I am currently working with DOORS and require assistance in comparing attributes of objects between two modules using DXL.

The objective is to compare attributes of objects across two modules. Each object possesses a unique identifier attribute, referred to as "ID". In the first module, this attribute is named "IE ID", while in the second module, it is labeled as "Req Id". Those attributes aids in identifying corresponding objects across modules. Once matching objects are identified based on this identifier, the goal is to compare other attributes of these objects to detect any disparities.

Although I have already developed some DXL code for this purpose, I am encountering challenges in efficiently comparing attributes and detecting differences between corresponding objects.

I require assistance in refining my DXL code to accurately compare attributes of objects across modules and efficiently identify any discrepancies.

Thank you for your assistance!

I tried this code :

```
Module m1 = current
Module m2 = edit("/Firts project/System/Module Verification")

Object obj1
Object obj2
string ID1
string ID2

ID1 = obj1."IE ID" ""

obj2 = obj1 in m2

if (obj2 != null) {
 
    ID2 = obj2."Req Id" ""

    if (ID1 == ID2) {
      
        for attr in obj1 do {
            
            if (attr != "IE ID") {
                string att1 = attr ""
                string att2 = obj2.(attr) ""

                if (att1 != att2) {
                    print "Différence détectée pour l'objet " obj1."Absolute Number" " :"
                    print "  Attribut : " attr
                    print "  Module 1 : " att1
                    print "  Module 2 : " att2
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
  
    print "Objet non trouvé dans le deuxième module pour l'objet " obj1."Absolute Number"
}
```

But it shows me a lot of error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Update in the code snippets after the discussion in the other answers

If the general loop shall be:

1. iterate over all objects in m1, setting o1 to the current object
2. Now iterate over all objects in m2 until you find the object o2 with the correct ID
3. now iterate over each attribute definition (defined in m1 or in m2) and compare the values.

Then the code for step 1 is

```
//here step 1
for obj1 in entire m1 do{
   ID1 = obj1."IE ID" ""
   //here step 2
}
```

Step 1 must be replaced if this is about DXL Layout columns or DXL Attributes. In these cases, the code for step 1 will just be

```
Module m1 = module obj
ID1 = obj."IE ID" ""
```

The code for step 2 will be

```
bool foundIt = false
for obj2 in entire m2 do {
   ID2 = obj2."Req Id" ""
   if (ID1 == ID2 ) {
      foundIt = true
      //here step 3
   }
}
if (!foundIt) {
   print "Objet non trouvé dans le deuxième module pour l'objet " obj1."Absolute Number" ""
}
```

The code for step 3 will be (if you iterate over the attributes defined in m1)

```
AttrDef ad1
for ad1 in m1 do {
   // if the AttrDef exists for objects
   if (ad1.object) {
     string attrName = ad1.name
     AttrDef ad2 = find (m1, attrName)
     // if an attribute of the same name exists in m2
     if (!null ad2) {
       string att1 = obj1.attrName ""
       string att2 = obj2.attrName ""
       if (att1 != att2) {   
          // in DXL layout column, replace "print" with "display"
          // in attribute DXL, replace print by one line containing "obj.attrDXLName=strMessage" with strMessage being a string variable filled with the message
          print "Différence détectée pour l'objet " obj1."Absolute Number" " :" 
          print "  Attribut : " attrName
          print "  Module 1 : " att1
          print "  Module 2 : " att2  "\n"
...
```

You might have to adopt this if some AttrDefs are defined as integer or Date, but the general steps should be rather clear now.

Comment: Hello Mike, 
I tried your code but I still have errors. Could you check  my response above please.

Answer (score 0):

I made the necessary modifications, below is the final code without syntax errors, but after execution, it only displays this message in the DXL column: 'Attribute DXL element failed,' and I can't identify the problem

```
Module m1 = current
Module m2 = edit(""/Firts project/System/Module Verification"")


Object obj2
string ID1
string ID2


   ID1 = obj."IE ID" ""
   bool foundIt = false
    for obj2 in entire m2 do {
        ID2 = obj2."Req Id" ""
        if (ID1 == ID2 ) {
        foundIt = true
        AttrDef ad1
            for ad1 in m1 do {
   // if the AttrDef exists for objects
                if (ad1.object) {
                     string attrName = ad1.name
                     string att1 = obj.attrName ""
                     string att2 = obj2.attrName ""
                     if (att1 != att2) {     
                        string resultMessage = "Différence détectée pour l'objet " obj."Absolute Number" " :" "  Attribut : " attrName "\n" "Module 1 : " att1 "\n" "  Module 2 : " att2
                        /* print "  Attribut : " attrName
                        print "  Module 1 : " att1
                        print "  Module 2 : " att2  "\n" */
                        
                        display resultMessage
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!foundIt) {
   display "Objet non trouvé dans le deuxième module pour l'objet " obj."Absolute Number" ""
    }
```

I also tried to write another code in parallel to specify the exact attribute I want to compare instead of all attributes (e.g., Absolute Number). The syntax of the code is correct, but the column remains empty without displaying any information or errors. The code is as follows:

```
Module m1 = current
Module m2 = edit("/Firts project/System/Module Verification")


Object obj2
string ID1
string ID2


   ID1 = obj."IE ID" ""
   bool foundIt = false
    for obj2 in entire m2 do {
        ID2 = obj2."Req Id" ""
        if (ID1 == ID2 ) {
        foundIt = true
                     string att1 = obj."Absolute Number" ""
                     string att2 = obj2."Absolute Number" ""
                     
                     if (att1 != att2) {     
                        string resultMessage = "Différence détectée pour l'objet " obj."Absolute Number" " :"  "\n" "Module 1 : " att1 "\n" "  Module 2 : " att2
                        
                        display resultMessage
                    }
        }
    }
    if (!foundIt) {
   display "Objet non trouvé dans le deuxième module pour l'objet " obj."Absolute Number" ""
    }
```

Comment: concerning your 2nd code, I tried it and got an error concerning line 1. `Module m1 = current` does not work always. Instead, you have to tell DXL that m1 is the module of `obj`, so that makes it `Module m1 = module obj`. This example works in my database

Comment: concerning the 1st code, with the same adoption of line 1, your code works in my DB, IF m1 and m2 have the same set of attribute definitions (e.g. ReqId and IE ID both exist in both modules). If this is not the case, you will have to detect in the loop whether the attribute of m1 really exists in m2. I updated my original answer to reflect this

Comment: The two codes are working fine now; the issue was just with the display function—it does not work. I used 'obj.attrDXLName = resultMessage' instead of 'display'. Thank you so much

Comment: A final question please, is it possible in DXL to identify the baseline I want to work with for the module '/First project/System/Module Verification' instead of the current one?

Comment: check answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094959/doors-dxl-for-changing-versioned-links-to-specific-target-baseline or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041356/how-to-load-a-specific-baseline-fron-ibm-doors-using-a-dxl-script or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906120/doors-dxl-link-to-non-existent-object-in-module-baseline on how to `load` a baseline instead of `edit`ing or `read`ing the current version.